# Move expander when an other expander is contracted and expanded using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a stackPanel with 2 expanders in it:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="0">
    <StackPanel Height="Auto" Margin="0" Width="Auto">
        <Expander Header="my expander"  Height="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Background="#00F19494" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid Background="#FFB86E6E"/>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Header="next expander"  Height="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Background="#00F19494" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid Background="#FF6E5C5C"/>
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I want the second expander to move up when the first expander is contracted and mave it down when the first expander is expanded, so it always appears at the bottom of the second expander's area.

Is there an easy way to do it using XAML?

Comment: Did you try removing the `Height` from the expander and adding it to the Grids inside expanders instead?

Comment: @Arsen did you manage to solve this?